# Dynamics CRM - Entity - Customise Left Navigation

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trying to customise the left navigation of a custom entity in CRM, I know I can rename the display areas for the linked entities however, I need the originals PLUS a few extras.  Is there any way to do this either by editing the sitemap or ISV.config files or some other method?

I.E. I want to do the following:

- Details
- Sales

  - Orders
  - Opportunities
- Service
- Marketing
- Custom Group 1

  - Custom Related Entity 1
  - Custom Related Entity 2
- Custom Group 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Matt, that in a supported fashion you're not going to be able to do this.  The only valid area's are "Info", "Sales", "Service", "Marketing" or blank.  If its something you really, really want I would recommend injecting nodes into the DOM to create the effect during the form load event.  Look at the source for MSCRM's "Sales" or "Service" NavBarAreas and then inject nodes to match.  Note that you can retrieve the NavBarItem's using document.getElementById using the ID attribute from NavBarItem.

Comment: Cant use the ID of the navbaritem as they are list items but I was able to iterate through the list and inject the required html to do this. I thought this was what I was going to have to do but wanted to make sure MS hadnt released a supported method of doing it. Roll on CRM 5.0 eh?

Comment: Nice, hadn't thought of this!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for KB22's solution, but if you want to stay supported, natively, you can't add new groups to the left nav. About the best you can do in this situation is rename one of the existing groups (Sales, Service, Marketing) if you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember that customizing CRM is pretty much of a PITA.
AFAIR one has to modify the MS-SQL VIEWS in the backend in order
to achieve such customizing.

Just tryin to point you towards the solution...